# How to create a Virtual Directory under a Site

Tags: asp.net, iis, web, iis-7.5

**Edit**: *I can't believe that I wasn't trying from my IIS but instead, I was running it directly from Visual studio which resulted in this error :) I can clearly see the images when I run it directly from IIS!*

I've created a website under IIS and have successfuly pointed it to my project. The path to my project under IIS is:

http://localhost:36011/cartoon/

I, then created a virtual directory under website cartoon named cartoon_images but it creates it under localhost:36011/cartoon_images/ instead of localhost:36011/cartoon/cartoon_images/

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see, virtual directory is under the website "cartoon" but I can't access it as cartoon/cartoon_images/

I'll need to give links to this virtual folder but I can't do it in this case if I'm not mistaken.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't believe that I wasn't trying from my IIS but instead, I was running it directly from Visual studio which resulted in this error :) I can clearly see the images when I run it directly from IIS!